# How to click on <a> tag using Curl

Tags: javascript, php, curl

how can I click on  tag  and then get the page content

I'm using this script to get aliexpress page  content to fetch the comments

```
$url = "some link";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
   $content = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Aliexpress  feedback  fetch the comments using Javascript after clinking on the following  tag

```
  <li data-trigger="feedback" data-role="trigger" class="ui-switchable-trigger">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.10010108.0.0">Feedback (27)</a>
  </li>
```

Can you guide me if possible

Comment: You can't do anything like this with curl. Check out Selenium

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use curl to get the page content, then once you have the content get the a tag's href value of the a tag you want and then run another curl function on that href link to get that a tag's page content.

**edit** 
@Phil is right. You will have to take the `data-spm-anchor-id` value with curl. But first you need to check the network in your lbrowser's inspector after you click the link to see how they are generating the link to get the page with that `data-spm-anchor-id`. Then you might be able to scrape the `data-spm-anchor-id` and jam it into a URL (that you get from the browser's network after clicking link) to which you can use curl on again.

Answer (score 0):

The page you trying to fetch is using JavaScript to load the content.

Using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) the JavaScript code **will not be run** and so you cannot get the *href* data unless a click is triggered which probably involves other dynamic requests.

[Selenium](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) may help you out since it's a kind of controlled Web Browser so it can read/fetch dynamic content.